# get a value of a key in list of dictionaries mySQL

Tags: mysql, list, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to fetch a value of a static key in the list of dictionaries. My data looks like this:

```
[{'Code': 6861741, 'id': 351, 'name': ca-pub}, {'Code': divison, 'id': 567, 'name': Magazine Division}]
```

Desired output is:

```
Magazine Division
```

How do I fetch the key of `name value` from the second dictionary in the list?

Thank you.

Comment: json_extract with path as $[1].name ?

Comment: What you posted isn't valid JSON, so none of the JSON functions in MySQL will work. Your only solution is to use some regexp or other substring function: